# Tweet testing program

Tags: java, twitter

Hello I have a working code for testing the amounts of hashtags, attributions, and links in the program but I need to test for if there is a tab key or space used after either the hashtags or attributions so as to not count them and have been having trouble.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a tweet: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        int length = input.length();
        int count = 0;
        int hashtags = 0, attributions = 0, links = 0;
        char letter;
        char letter2;
        if (length > 140) {
            System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (length - 140));
        } else {
            while (count < length) {
                letter = input.charAt(count);
                if (letter == '#') {
                    if (input.startsWith("#\t", count)) {

                    } else {
                        hashtags++;
                        count++;
                    }

                    if (letter == '@') {
                        if (input.startsWith("@\t", count)) {
                            count++;
                        } else {
                            attributions++;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (letter == 'h') {
                        input = input.toLowerCase();
                        if (input.startsWith("http://", count)) {
                            links++;
                            count++;
                        } else {
                            count++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Length Correct");
                System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + hashtags);
                System.out.println("Number of Attributions: " + attributions);
                System.out.println("Number of Links: " + links);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If an answer is helpful, please remember to accept it, and if you have further questions, feel free to use the comments.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way:

Call [Character.isWhitespace(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).  (Example: `Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(count+1))`).  Obviously you'd need to check to make sure that the hashtag isn't the last character.

Some unsolicited advice:

- Try not to use `.startsWith()`, because that is limited to specific characters, and you'd have to add a different `if` statement for each character you wanted to check for (space, tab, etc.).  I recognize that this might not work in all cases, such as your `.startsWith("http:")` case.  In this case, `.startsWith()` can still work, but use the count to get the index: `input.substring(count).startsWith("http:")` (Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-))
- One issue your code currently faces is that the checking of spaces always goes from the beginning of a string.  For the input string `#\tabc #def #ghi`, it will show 0 hashtags, because it fails the space on the first case, which is the one it's checking every time.
- If you are constantly doing `if (letter=='<char>')`, you might want to try using a switch statement (e.g. `switch(letter)`).  In Java, this works on characters (or Strings, if you are using Java 8).  This can help avoid difficult-to-trace errors regarding bracket placement, etc.